# copy files with double quotes and matching pattern

Tags: linux, shell, unix, cp

I have files which need to be copied to the folder. There would be matching pattern. For example: If test.cls is there. Along with that file, test.cls-meta.xml also needs to be copied. I would use test.cls* to copy both the files
Usually i use the following command

```
cp test.cls* directory/
```

some file names have spaces in between. So I had to put files in double quotes to handle the spaces. But it is failing as it is assuming * as part of name. How to resolve this problem?

```
cp "test.cls*" directory/
cp: cannot stat ‘test.cls*’: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the `*` outside of the quotes, otherwise it wouldn't get expanded:

```
cp "test foo.cls"* /dir
```

- https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html#Shell-Expansions
- https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html